# c# json read not happening

Tags: c#, json, file

This isn't working (the file exists, it reads it ok, then none of the loops fire) and I don't know why..

```
if (File.Exists("my.json"))
{
    var response = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("my.json");
    var domains = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<jsonRead>>(response);
    foreach (jsonRead domain in domains)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(domain.Password);
        var folders = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<jsonReadDeep>>(domain.Folders);

        foreach (jsonReadDeep folder in folders)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(folder.localServer);                    
        }
    }
}
```

the classes

```
class jsonRead
{
    public string Folders;
    public string Name;
    public string User;
    public string Password;
    public string Url;
}

class jsonReadDeep
{
    public string localFolder;
    public string serverFolder;
}
```

the json

```
[   
  {
    "Folders": [
      {
        "localFolder": "C:\\test",
        "serverFolder": "Default/"
      }
    ],
    "Name": "hi",
    "User": "there",
    "Password": "secret",
    "Url": "https://mydomain.com"
  } 
]
```

Comment: it's ok it was simply this: //public ArrayList Folders// in jsonRead - I would have assumes that the json would have decayed and passed it as a string - but obviously not;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define `jsonRead` like below:

```
class jsonRead
{
    public jsonReadDeep[] Folders;
    public string Name;
    public string User;
    public string Password;
    public string Url;
}
```

And your code:

```
var response = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("my.json");
var domains = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<jsonRead>>(response);

foreach (jsonRead domain in domains)
{
    MessageBox.Show(domain.Password);

    foreach (jsonReadDeep folder in domain.Folders)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(folder.localFolder);
    }
}
```